# Let contributors fork private repository, but not contribute to master

Tags: git, github, permissions, git-fork

I need to make a private repository, let contributors fork his own copy of the main repository (so I have to add them as contributors in GitHub), but I do not want them to be able to work directly in the main repository (origin). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use an `organization` to gain a finer grain of access controll, see https://help.github.com/categories/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/ specially    https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization-repository/ for details on permissons

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the only option, I guess I'd have to pay. Thank you @joran !